# Should original authors be included in pom.xml developers tag after project is forked?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am considering forking a long lived but seemingly abandoned OSS project. In my updated pom.xml, should I include the developers of original work to give them credit since they are responsible for the 99% of the code, or just new maintainers, as the [Maven POM Reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Developers) would imply:

> All projects consist of files that were created, at some time, by a
> person. Like the other systems that surround a project, so to do the
> people involved with a project have a stake in the project. Developers
> are presumably members of the project's core development. Note that,
> although an organization may have many developers (programmers) as
> members, it is not good form to list them all as developers, but only
> those who are immediately responsible for the code. **A good rule of
> thumb is, if the person should not be contacted about the project,
> they do not need to be listed here**.

Comment: 1. I'm voting to close, as this is opinion-based. 2. I think the last sentence already gives a very strong argument **not** to include them. If you fork a project then *you* take over responsibility. *They* shouldn't be contacted with bug reports and improvement requests for that fork. You can always highlight the work of former developers in some other way (thank them in the readme or other unstructured data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just the pom.xml file. Do like it is written in the rule of thumb.

For a branch or a fork the history and dependencies or codebase should be clarified elsewhere, e.g. git, GitHub.com, GitLab.com, a project page, the docs...